# Bind data to different element based on function/content of the data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

While reading about the datatemplates I noticed you can choose different templates based on the type of data. - However can one also do this for different *content* of the data?

My modelview provides a list of data, in principle it's just a list of tuples (bound in a custom class to make typing easier) with `Tuple<ImageData, AltText>`. 
The type of the property in the ModelView is:

```
ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ThumbDispData>
```

With `ThumbDispData`:

```
public class ThumbDispData
{
    public ImageData Idhl { get; set; }
    public string AltText { get; set; }
}
```

Now I wish to display an `Image` if it can (`ImageData.Source` is non null) - Otherwise it should show an alt-text.

The xaml or the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.ThumbPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:test="clr-namespace:test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type test:ThumbDispData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AltText}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Well above only shows the alt-text (which works): how would I create a selector based on the content of ThumbDispData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tt" DataType="{x:Type test:ThumbDispData}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AltText}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="img" DataType="{x:Type test:ThumbDispData}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Idhl}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:Selector x:Key="selector" TextTemplate="{StaticResource tt}" ImageTemplate="{StaticResource img}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

---

```
public class Selector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ImageTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TextTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ThumbDispData data = item as ThumbDispData;
        if (data != null && data.Idhl != null)
            return ImageTemplate;


        return TextTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> would I create a selector based on the content of ThumbDispData.

You would typically write a subclass of [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx), in which you check the `Idhl` property and return a different template object depending on whether it's null or not. Typically, the template would be a resource, which you load dynamically in the selector.

But your scenario is simple enough that I would use styles instead. For example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type test:ThumbDispData}"
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AltText}">
      <TextBlock.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="TextBlock">
          <Setter Visibility="Visible"/>
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Idhl}" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </p:Style>
        </p:Style>
      </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <Image Source="{Binding Idhl}">
      <Image.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="Image">
          <Setter Visibility="Collapsed"/>
          <p:Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Idhl}" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Visibility="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </p:Style>
        </p:Style>
      </Image.Style>
    </Image>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Notes:

- Strictly speaking, you don't need the `<Setter Visibility="Visible"/>` in the `TextBlock` style, since that's the default value. I put it there because it helps document the symmetry between the styles of the two elements.
- The `xmlns:p` declaration is there only as a Stack Overflow work-around, because the XML formatter doesn't handle the XAML `Style` element correctly otherwise. In real XAML, you can leave that out and just use the `Style` name directly instead of `p:Style`.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with such an approach is that it is look before you leap. Image data is inherently volatile (the source might be corrupt/represent a format that the `Image` class can't display), so isn't there a way to datatrigger if and only if `Image` can display the source?

Comment: _"isn't there a way to datatrigger if and only if Image can display the source?"_ -- yes, of course. But your question doesn't provide enough context to provide a specific example of that. You'll note that the above example doesn't even take into account that you're using some user-defined type `ImageData` for the property. I doubt in your real code you'd bind directly to `Idhl`, since you seem to have wrapped the image source in some other type.

Comment: But the basic idea is the same; trigger on _some_ property that _does_ indicate whether the data is valid, and bind the `Source` property to a valid image source (which is presumably `null` when the data is invalid).